# mysql query to delete/remove whitespaces in between a string?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Is there a Query or way in MySql to delete whitespaces in-between a String ?
For Example - If I've a String **'Auto Robot Cars'** , the result should be 
**'AutoRobotCars'** 
I'm aware of TRIM function  in MySql but it only deletes Leading & Trailing spaces not the WhiteSpaces in-between the String.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot in please

Comment: @connorg98 Screenshots are not the preferred way of provided sample data. Always copy/pastable text.

Comment: Use replace function.

Comment: @Error_2646 why are you even replying to me? i am asking for a screenshot of the blank space so i can see it

Comment: @connorg98 Because you shouldn't be asking for screenshots. Images are worse than text and OP is a new user who shouldn't be getting bad information. Case in point, from a screenshot you can't differentiate 4 spaces from a tab. That is important here.

Comment: @Error_2646 i have asked for  a screenshot so i can debug, i prefer to see the issue with my own eyes when i am fixing. I didnt ask for screenshots of code i wanted to see the output. P.S OP has been a member for a year and 5 months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe MySQL has a replace function - REPLACE(YourString, " ","")

Edit:

1.) Do you need this to remove tabs and new lines as well (all whitespace not just ' ')?

2.) Do you want to leave leading and trailing spaces as-is?

Comment: It Worked , Thanks a lot .
Its a bit Strange I've Tried the REPLACE() function but it didn't worked that time , may be some silly mistakes were there.
Anyways Thanks.

Comment: @Sumit Might not be a silly mistake. Could you have been trying to remove a tab rather than a space? A more robust approach would be REGEXP_REPLACE(YourString,'\s','') As this will handle tabs as well.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has a Trim & REPLACE function, Please review below example.

```
+------------+
| trim(code) |
+------------+
| Plan 607   |
| Plan 608   |
| Plan 609   |
| Plan 610   |
| Plan 611   |
| Plan 612   |
| Plan 613   |
| Plan 614   |
| Plan 615   |
| Plan 616   |
+------------+
```

Now you can use

```
select REPLACE(code,' ','') from table_name;
```

This will return below result

```
+---------+
| code    |
+---------+
| Plan607 |
| Plan608 |
| Plan609 |
| Plan610 |
| Plan611 |
| Plan612 |
| Plan613 |
| Plan614 |
| Plan615 |
| Plan616 |
+---------+
```